# How to use pattern matching for two or more regular expressions in scala

Tags: scala, web-crawler

I don't understand how to use pattern matching for two or more regular expressions. For instance, I wrote the following program:

```
import scala.io.Source.{fromInputStream}
import java.io._
import java.net._
object craw
{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val url=new URL("http://contentexplore.com/iphone-6-amazing-looks/")
    val content=fromInputStream(url.openStream).getLines.mkString("\n")
    val x="<a href=(\"[^\"]*\")[^<]".r.
      findAllIn(content).
      toList.
      map(x=>x.substring(16,x.length()-2)).
      mkString("").
      split("/").
      mkString("").
      split(".com").
      mkString("").
      split("www.").
      mkString("").
      split(".html").
      toList
    print(x)
  }
}
```

The above reads in all the anchor tags.

```
import scala.io.Source.{fromInputStream}
import java.io._
import java.net._
object new1
{
  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val url=new URL("http://contentexplore.com/iphone-6-amazing-looks/")
    val content=fromInputStream(url.openStream).getLines.mkString("\n")
    val x="<p>.*?</p>".r.
      findAllIn(content).
      toList.
      map(x=>x.substring(3,x.length()-4)).
      mkString("").
      split("</strong>").
      mkString("").
      split("</em>").
      mkString("").
      split(";").
      mkString("").
      split("<em>").
      mkString("").
      split("<strong>").
      mkString("").
      split("&nbsp").
      toList
    print(x)
  }
}
```

The above reads in all the paragraph tags.

I want to combine these two regular expressions into a single program, using pattern matching. Can guide me regarding how to use more than two regular expressions?

**NOTE** This question has to do with the combining regular expressions, and not with how to efficiently parse HTML.

Comment: [You shouldn't parse html with regex](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/406435). Instead you could use [html parser](http://blog.dub.podval.org/2010/08/scala-and-tag-soup.html).

Comment: Thank you so much senia but as i am a beginner i am unable to follow the example which you have given.Kindly suggest me how to write more than one regular expressions in patternmatching . for instance i want to write a case which retrieves all the anchor tags and other one to retrieve paragraph tags.Kindly suggest me.Thank you

Comment: again: don't parse html with regex, I found jsoup(http://jsoup.org/cookbook/) to be very simple to use. It only requires that you know how to port examples from java to scala, which is simple for that case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As noted in comments, it is not recommended to use regex to parse HTML files(or any other technique unless you are sure you can't/don't want to use some of the existing ones, like jsoup).

For educational purposes, here is one way to chain regex with pattern matching(using regex as extractors):

```
val LinkPattern = "<a href=(\"[^\"]*\")[^<]".r
val ParagraphPattern = "<p>.*?</p>".r
xmlNodeString match {
   case LinkPattern(c) => //c bound to capture group here
   case ParagraphPattern(d) => //d bound to capture group here
   case _ =>
}
```

note: this assumes each individual node you are parsing is xmlNodeString, so you would need to traverse the XML nodes, matching one at a time.